# Parse Json response iphone objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have the following response in json, and I am unsure on how to parse it

```
[{"WordArray":[{"Id":11,"Word1":"ODDER","Category":"Dyr","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"},{"Id":225,"Word1":"PRAG","Category":"International by","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"}]},{"WordArray":[{"Id":3,"Word1":"TIGER","Category":"Dyr","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"},{"Id":154,"Word1":"BOLLE","Category":"Mad og drikke","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"}]},
{"WordArray":[{"Id":3,"Word1":"TIGER","Category":"Dyr","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"},{"Id":147,"Word1":"PIZZA","Category":"Mad og drikke","Differculty":1,"Language":"Danish"}]}]
```

I have tried the following without luck

```
NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableArray * roundWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]retain ];

roundWords = [json objectAtIndex:i];
```

json contains my 3 'WordArray' but im unsure how to proceed..
How do I iterate over each item in `WordArray` and NSLog the `Word1` value, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Also note that this is not even remotely related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i iterate over each item in WordArray and NSLog the Word1 value

Use fast enumeration.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Word1"]);
}
```

By the way, your code is wrong at several places:

```
NSMutableArray *roundWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] retain];
roundWords = [json objectAtIndex:i];
```

One, one doesn't use `retain` chained with `alloc` like this. Use `init` for initializing an  object.

Two: unless you use ARC (which you don't), you're leaking memory with that line - the pointer to the original array is discarded since you reassign something else to it.

Three: `[json objectAtIndex:i]` is not an `NSMutableArray` - it's an `NSDictionary` (which is **immutable,** by the way. Declarations ain't magic - however you declare your variable, it won't affect the fact that `NSJSONSerialization` returns an immutable dictionary unless specified otherwise).